# Grouping function calls for convinience when working interactively

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook

I use the iPython Notebook both as my IDE and where I actually do the work for which I write my code. For my purposes I have created a lot of functions, which I would like to be able to batch call without creating a lot separate script files.

For now I run the cells containing all the function calls, and while that works, I find to be rather cumbersome when rerunning a lot of basic code and would rather like the convenience and crisp look of just calling something like

```
do_cleaning
```

or

```
generate_setup_variables
```

I know that I could write some wrapper functions, but that would lead to a rather prodigious return statement, as I am creating a lot of variables. Alternatively I could end the wrapper functions by sending the content of the functions local namespace to the global one - but how to?

So basically, how do I run a lot of function calls in a convenient manner without generating external script files?

Kind regards,
Rasmus